# Permission Denied - when removing Snap Gimp Package

Tags: permissions, uninstall, snap, delete, gimp

I want to uninstall gimp. I type the following command to do so:

```
sudo snap remove gimp
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Save data of snap "gimp" in automatic snapshot set #15 (cannot create archive: tar: 281/.config/GIMP/2.10/patterns/GPS-Pat: Cannot open: Permission denied (and 18 more))
```

I also get a permission error if I try to remove GIMP through the GUI Ubuntu Software Centre

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 5):

Ended up solving with:

`snap remove --purge gimp`